# output observation if meets criteria

Tags: sas

Here is my data set:
    Name       Mark     Math1 Math2  Math3
    -------------------------------------

```
Justin  AA1 1   0   1   
Justin  BB1 1   1   1   
Justin  BA1 0   1   0
Justin      BC2 0       0       1
```

and here is the SAS code to create it

```
         DATA Student1;
         INPUT Name $  Mark $ Math1 Math2 Math3;
        DATALINES;
        Justin  AA1  1 0 1
        Justin  BB1  1 1 1
        Justin  BA1  0 1 0
        Justin  BC2  0 0 1
        ;
```

I would like to evaluate Math1 and output the mark next to it if 1 is encountered, however because that position was used in Math1 it can't be used again in Math2 i.e. output Justin is AA1 for Math1, BB1 for Math2 (because that's where the first one is in the column) and BC2 for Math3 because even though we have a 1 on the same row with AA1 and BB1 these two marks have already been used in var Math1 and Math2.

This is what the output data set should look like

```
       data Student2;
       input name $ Math1 $ Math2 $ Math3 $;
        datalines;
       Justin AA1 BB1 BC2
       ;
```

Can I do this using arrays?

Comment: This seems like a problem that involves manipulating your input data set before outputing the solution data set. If you could post a more accurate view of your input data set, a solution could be found. Could you include a data step with datalines so that a solution could be tested?

Comment: Is there a mandatory order from math1 to math3? for example if the second line is "Justin  BB1  0 0 1", then we skip this line or output bb1 and skip the fourth line bc2 since math3 has been used?

Comment: That's correct Robbie we skip the line because 1 is an indicator in this case 1 is in column three so we output the mark in the fourth line. The mark has to be unique i.e. can't be outputted twice - this is the hard part

Answer (score 0):

Array may be not sufficient in this case. The follow is a solution (hopeful) using IML (looks bulky though). I speculate that you may need to deal with more than one student, so make it applicable in multiple names case. Please comment if there is any error.

```
  DATA Student1;
    INPUT Name $  Mark $ Math1 Math2 Math3;
      DATALINES;
        Justin  AA1  1 0 1
        Justin  BB1  1 1 1
        Justin  BA1  0 1 0
        Justin  BC2  0 0 1
        Wayne   AB1  1 0 1
        Wayne   BC1   0 0 1
        Wayne  BD2    0 1 0
        Wayne  BE3   1 1 1
        ;
  quit;

proc iml;
  use student1;
  read all var{name mark} into x;
  read all var{math1 math2 math3} into y;
z=j(nrow(y),ncol(y),'mon');
i=1;
   do j=2 to nrow(x);
     if x[j,1]^=x[j-1,1] | j=nrow(x) then do;
      if j=nrow(x) then j=j+1;
        do k=1 to 3;
          do l=i to j-1;
            if y[l,k]=1 then do;
             y[l,k:3]=0;
             y[l+1:j-1,k]=0;
             z[i:j-1,k]=x[l,2];
             end;
           end;
         end;
         i=j;
     end;
    end;
    colname={'math1', 'math2', 'math3'};
create new from z[colname=colname];
append from z;
quit;

data new;
merge student1(keep=name) new;
run;

proc sort data=new out=new nodupkey;
by name;
run;
```

Comment: thanks Robbie-great solution - I thought it may involve IML - I was wandering whether there is a way around it